# Fail to send email by utility class

Tags: csom, sputility

I have utility class to send email.

currently i am facing error :-

> a recipient must be specified

```
EmailProperties emailp = new EmailProperties();

emailp.To = new string[] {
    "robbstark@gmail.com"
};

emailp.From = email;
emailp.Body = "<b>Hello</b>";
emailp.Subject = "New Email";


Utility.SendEmail(clientContext, emailp);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Pradip already mentioned that it is not possible to send email to the external people using `Utility` so can consider `System.Net.Mail` to serve your purpose.

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("jane@contoso.com", "Jane " + (char) 0xD8 + " Clayton", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
```

Find full reference in ***[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)***

Answer (score 5):

The default `SPUtility`, `SendMail` functionality in SharePoint is limited. And you can only send emails to people who are known within the site collection. If you only want to send email to people within site collection, then make sure you use `EnsureUser()` to check the availibility in site collection.

**Snippet**:

```
private void SendEmail(ClientContext clientContext)
{
    User sendToUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser("robbstark@gmail.com");
    clientContext.Load(sendToUser);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    string email = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.GetCurrentUserEmailAddresses(clientContext).Value;

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.EmailProperties properties = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.EmailProperties();
    properties.To = new string[] { sendToUser.Email };
    properties.Subject = "subject";
    properties.Body = "body";

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail(clientContext, properties);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Refer [this good article](http://manasbhardwaj.net/how-to-send-email-using-sharepoint/) by Manas Bhardwaj for more.

Comment: your Code Snippet , is working but only for some particular user, not for all users

Comment: Make sure those users are known to the site collection that you are using with `clientContext`.

Comment: yes i have checked , my Current user is known to site collection..